# Error are not caught properly when using a centralized prisma client for the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, prisma, fastify

I'm currently working using an approach where I'm using a centralized prisma client.

**db.js**

```
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
const prisma = new PrismaClient();



module.exports = prisma;
```

**prismaMiddleware.js**

```
const prisma = require("../db/db");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
  try {
    if (
      params.model === "seller" &&
      (params.action === "create" || params.action === "update")
    ) {
      const seller = params.args.data;
      if (seller.password) {
        seller.password = await bcrypt.hash(seller.password, 10);
      }
    }

    const result = await next(params);

    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})
```

;

**controller.js**

```
const prisma = require("../db/db"); // centralized prisma client

//New prisma client
// const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");
// const prisma = new PrismaClient();

exports.addProduct = async (req, res) => {
try{
    ...
}catch(error){
  conosle.log(error);
  res.status(500).send({error:error.message});
}
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = [
  {
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/product",
    handler: controller.addProduct,
    preHandler:auth
  }]
```

**app.js**

```
routes.forEach((route, index) => {
    fastify.route(route);
});
```

But there is something wrong with this approach when I'm using this approach and using this in my other files of API routes try-catch is not able to throw the error properly i'm getting a log for the error but the response is send as 200, but when creating a new prisma client in the same file and using that, error are caught and server response is 500.

I have tested in other applications also and go the same results, So is it a prisma or fastify problem, as according to the documentation of Prisma ORM it is suggested to use a single prisma client for the application.l